# Dynamically change child element order in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background**

I have an angular table directive where the user can customise the column order (via drag and drop). Data rows use the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<table columno>
    <tr>
        <th>Column Head 1</th>
        <th>Column Head 2</th>
        <th>Column Head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Simplified fiddle using buttons instead of drag and drop @ https://jsfiddle.net/jn1y44s6/5/.

**Problem:**

When the user moves say Column 1 to become Column 2, the move works fine. Problem is when a new object is added to the `items` array the new columns are in the original unchanged order.

I understand `ng-repeat` is using the compiled template as constructed at runtime but how can I make the new column order persist for new objects too?

Comment: Sounds like you need a nested ng-repeat, where the columns are in their own object that gets modified on a scoped basis (per row).

Comment: The problem you're facing is because you're mixing jQuery DOM manipulation and AngularJS. Ideally, instead of changing the DOM through jQuery, why don't you instead try and change the data programatically?

Comment: I have an idea - will use 'row' child directives to `$watch` an array of column order and set the column order class. Will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Html code

```
<div ng-app="fiddle" columnly>
   <button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
   <button ng-click="move()">Move Column 1</button>
   <table>
      <tr class="row">
         <th class="column move">Row 0 Head 1</th>
         <th class="column">Row 0 Head 2</th>
         <th class="column">Row 0 Head 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <td class="column first move">Row {{item}} Column 1</td>
         <td class="column second">Row {{item}} Column 2</td>
         <td class="column">Row {{item}} Column 3</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('fiddle', []);
app.directive('columnly', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, $scope) {
            var count = 6;
            scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            scope.firstClick = true;
            scope.addRow = function() {
                scope.items.push(count++);
                if ($("tr th:nth-child(2)").hasClass('move')) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var abc = $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(0).html();
                        var def = $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(1).html()
                        $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(1).html(abc);
                        $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(0).html(def);
                        $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(1).addClass('move')
                        $("tr:nth-child(" + count + ")").children().eq(0).removeClass('move')
                    });
                }
            };
            scope.move = function() {
                jQuery.each($("table tr"), function() {
                    $(this).children().eq(1).after($(this).children().eq(0));
                });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle link

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/Anvesh2727/jn1y44s6/10/][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but this solution does not scale in that the user could move any column.